# how to rewrite html url as directory in htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all of my category urls as directories instead of long html pages. How do I do that? (The site is homewetbar.com if you need to look at the directory structure further to understand how it currently works.)

For Example:

**First level category:**

www.site.com/great-gift-ideas-c-35.html

I would like to display instead as:
www.site.com/great-gift-ideas-c-35

**Second level category:**

www.site.com/great-gift-ideas-gifts-recipient-c-35_85.html

I would like to display instead as:
www.site.com/great-gift-ideas/gifts-recipient-c-35_85

**Third level category:**

www.site.com/gifts-recipient/groomsmen-gifts-c-35_85_43.html

I would like to display instead as:
www.site.com/gifts-recipient/groomsmen-gifts-c-35_85_43

OR:
www.site.com/great-gift-ideas/gifts-recipient/groomsmen-gifts-c-35_85_43 (whichever is easier)

Answer (score 0):

I think mod_rewrite is what you are looking for, [here is a link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite) with how to set it up and how to start rewriting your urls. It should have enough information for what you are looking for, for more advanced stuff you will want to know more about regular expressions, but your examples are simple enough.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^great-gift-ideas-c-35.html$ great-gift-ideas-c-35
```

this should work for your first example, the rest just replace out the appropriate urls.

Comment: We currently have a rewrite in the htaccess that then goes to php which processes and creates the url. This is the line from htaccess RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}  What I understand you to be saying is let php do it's thing to create the url then rewrite it in htaccess. Is that correct? How do we rewrite them dynamically vs one at I time like your example above?

Comment: yes, htaccess will rewrite the url but php _get variables are accessed the same way they are before the rewrite. as for dynamically rewriting all of them you could use something like in NuTTyX's answer, but also add a rewrite rule for .php files. The only difficulty is rewriting _get variables, which you may have to end up writing individually. I don't know too much about them.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to rewrite all the `href` in your site to delete the ".html" part. Then, add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

That would make any URL without the ".html" work as if it had it

Answer (score 0):

Just check out this site: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php it generate all you need

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?example=$1 [L]
```

Changing example to what you need should do it

Comment: This is helpful for one by one redirects, however I need to dynamically rewrite all of them for current and any future urls which go to categories. Designated by the -c- in the url string. How would I do that for all category urls dynamically?